# String permutations

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

Print the biggest-size subset of strings in the input that are all permutations of each other. If there are ties, any one will do. If no strings are permutations of each other (for example, only one string was given or the strings contain distinct characters), this is just one of the strings. If no strings were passed in , do not output anything or output an empty list.

Test cases:

```
Input => Output
["ABCDE", "EDBCA", "XYZ", "ZYX", "ZXY"] => ["XYZ", "ZYX", "ZXY"]
["A"] => ["A"]
```

Comment: Is that an example of just input or are the outputs also in that same line? Can you include clear examples of expected output, with at least two test cases?

Comment: To make this a challenge suitable for CGCC is not enough to just translate the old [Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/957318/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) question.

Comment: This needs an objective winning criterion, such as "smallest number of bytes wins"

Comment: @close voters: please don’t close code-golf questions for not having an objective primary winning criterion. If it’s code-golf, the winning criterion is “fewest bytes of source code wins”.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, presuming that the only problem was that the winning criterion was inadvertently omitted -- although it's clear because of the code-golf tag.  (If there's some other issue, please post it, of course.)

Comment: I think a lot of the confusion about the spec came was due to a literal translation from Russian using terms that don't mean the same thing in a technical sense. I tried to edit to clarify a bit.

Comment: Are the characters in each string guaranteed to be distinct or can there be duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
.¡{}éθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79DC6trDK8/t@P8/WsnRydnFVUlHQcnVxcnZEcSIiIwCUVGREWAqIlIpFgA)

```
.¡ }      # group the input strings by:
  {       #  sort (all permutations of each other will be identical when sorted)
    é     # sort the groups by length
     θ    # output the last (longest) group
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 267 bytes

SQL queries was totally made to solve this type of question

```sql
SELECT top 1WITH TIES x FROM(SELECT(SELECT a FROM(SELECT
top 999substring(x,number+1,1)a,*FROM
@,spt_values WHERE type='P'and number<len(x)ORDER BY a)c
WHERE x=t.x for xml path(''),type).value('.','char(9)')v,x FROM @ t)z 
ORDER BY-count(*)over(PARTITION BY v),-len(x)
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/GXJZ40415)**

Comment: What the fuck I'm actually intimidated now

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
üñ ñl
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=/PEg8Ww&input=WyJBQkNERSIsICJFREJDQSIsICJYWVoiLCAiWllYIiwgIlpYWSJdCi1R)

```
üñ ñl     :Implicit input of array
ü         :Sort & group by
 ñ        :  Sorted strings
   ñ      :Sort by
    l     :  Length
          :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 36 bytes

```perl6
{max .classify(~*.comb.sort){*}||''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjexQkEvOSexuDgzrVKjTksvOT83Sa84v6hEs1qrtqZGXb32vzVXWn6RgkZOZl5qsaZCNZeCQnFipUKahp5rmKOPJlft/2glRydnF1clHQUlVxcnZ0cQIyIyCkRFRUaAqYhIpVguoDoQGQsA)

Output an empty string for an empty input. If we could output something else, for example `-Inf`, then this could be:

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 31 bytes

```perl6
*.classify(~*.comb.sort){*}.max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfSy85J7G4ODOtUqMOyM7PTdIrzi8q0azWqtXLTaz4b82Vll@koJGTmZdarKlQzaWgUJxYqZCmoeca5uijyVX7P1rJ0cnZxVVJR0HJ1cXJ2RHEiIiMAlFRkRFgKiJSKZYLqA5ExgIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```python
lambda A,S=sorted:A and max([[y for y in A if S(x)==S(y)]for x in A],key=len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYu9CsMgGEX3PsWHk4JTx4KD@XkCF03qYFGpNNFgM8SntySUQqGd7r2ce5ay3lM8V8@udTLzzRrgVLBnyquzFw4mWpjNhsexgE8ZCoQIHIIHgTfCmMCF6B1sB9D04QqbXCR1ySGu4PGIeNN2PaKApBr26Lum5XsZlDxCKqTJ6Yfweb7Nv8LX1KS@AA)

2 bytes thx to [wilkben](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88089/wilkben).

The `A and...` is only required to deal with the empty input.

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##dYu9CsMgGEX3PsWHk4JTx4KD@XkCF03qYFGpNNFgM8SntySUQqGd7r2ce5ay3lM8V8@udTLzzRrgVLBnyquzFw4mWpjNhsexgE8ZCoQIHIIHgTfCmMCF6B1sB9D04QqbXCR1ySGu4PGIeNN2PaKApBr26Lum5XsZlDxCKqTJ6Yfweb7Nv8LX1KS@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
0({>\:#&>)/:~&></.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DTSq7WKslNXsNPWt6tTsbPT1Yv9rcnGlJmfkK6Qp2FjrxRsCdTk6Obu4KkRERim4ujg5OypERUYoREVEqsPVqTuq/wcA)

*-2 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog*

Similar approach to Grimmy's answer.

Comment: Bring `{` into the () and you don't need [:

Comment: Very nice, thank you @FrownyFrog

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 54 bytes

```clj
#(some val(sort-by(comp count val)>(group-by sort %)))
```

Returns `nil` for empty input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappD2X1mjOD83VaEsMQfIKCrRTarUSM7PLVBIzi/NKwEJa9pppBfllxYAZRRAKhRUNTU1/2tyaRQUZeaV5ORppClEKzk6Obu4KukoKLm6ODk7ghgRkVEgKioyAkxFRCrFaqJrwhAC8v8DAA)